# Move values from one array to another and remove them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 20 number array. Now I pick (randomly) 5 of these and i wanna put them into another empty array. How can I do? And also, how can I hide them from the first array when they're displayed? Thank you all.

```
var tenNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 42, 178, 54, 76, 32, 12, 38, 154, 234];
var randomNumbers = document.getElementById("demo");
randomNumbers.innerHTML = tenNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*tenNumbers.length)];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'hide them from the first array when they're displayed ' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you should be able to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove a random element from the original array, then push that result onto a new array:

```js
var tenNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 42, 178, 54, 76, 32, 12, 38, 154, 234];
var outArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    outArray.push(tenNumbers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*tenNumbers.length), 1)[0]);
}
document.write(outArray + "<br />" + tenNumbers);
```

Comment: You've beat me to it :D. `splice` is indeed the answer the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var tenNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 42, 178, 54, 76, 32, 12, 38, 154, 234];

var randomNumbersArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    randomNumbersArray.push(tenNumbers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*tenNumbers.length), 1));
}

document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomNumbersArray.join("<br />");
```

```html
<div id="random"></div>
```

This should do it.

- Run loop until second array has five entries.
- delete entry from original array with splice to avoid doubles.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var tenNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 42, 178, 54, 76, 32, 12, 38, 154, 234];

var randNums = [];

var randomNumbers = document.getElementById("demo");

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
   var index = getRandomInt(0, tenNumbers.length - 1);        
   randNums.push(tenNumbers[index]); 
   randomNumbers.innerHTML += tenNumbers[index] + ", ";
   tenNumbers.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pick 5 random elements and move them to a new array using `.sort` & `.splice` one-liner:

```
var outArray = tenNumbers.sort(function(){ return Math.random() - 0.5; }).splice(0,5);
```