# Javascript: Trying to randomly move items from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I've been stuck for a couple hours now trying to randomly select one item from one array (players) to another (team1).

I've got it working by doing something else with splice, but unfortunately splice creates an array itself with the removed items and so I ended up getting an array with an array.

This is what I got so far:

```
var players = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"];

var team1 = [];
var team2 = [];

var select = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
var tmp;

if (team1.length < 2) {
  tmp.push(players.splice(select, 1));
  team1.push(tmp.pop);
}

console.log(team1);
console.log(tmp);
console.log(players);
```

If I'm doing this all wrong I'm sorry, still pretty new to this website, help is appreciated.

Comment: To clarify I want an item to be randomly removed from one array then added to another.

Comment: check here it is repeated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829166/move-values-from-one-array-to-another-and-remove-them

Comment: Duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to select the first element from the array while splicing and pushing to team,

```
var players = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8"];

var team1 = [];
var team2 = [];

var tmp = [];
while (team1.length < 4) {
  tmp.push(players.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length - 1), 1)[0]);
  team1.push(tmp.pop());
}

while (team2.length < 4) {
  tmp.push(players.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length - 1), 1)[0]);
  team2.push(tmp.pop());
}

console.log(team1);
console.log(team2);
console.log(tmp);
console.log(players);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, why is that may I ask? I didn't even know you can just select the index at the end of push and splice like that

Comment: Whatever may be the result if a function returns a value in array like structure(array or nodelist) we can access the values inside that by indexing.

Comment: Sorry one more question, I changed it into a while loop so I can divide them into two teams, and it only works a portion of the time, the other times it will place undefined into the team arrays, do you know why? Here's the link: https://codepen.io/Buckets/pen/wqQxzP?editors=1111

Comment: You have to create different random select for each item in while loop, since you are using same select, at some point select value becomes higer than the array size since we are slicing it from parent array. I've updated my answer take a look

Answer (score 1):

you try like this in your scenario

```
var players = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"];

var team1 = [];
var team2 = [];
var temp = players.slice();

for(i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
     var select = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
     console.log(select);
     if (team1.length <= temp.length/2) {
        team1.push(temp[select]);
      }
      temp.splice(select, 1);
}
team2 = temp.slice();

console.log('team 1 ---',team1);
console.log('team 2 ---',team2);
console.log('players ---', players);
```